# Laravel Eloquent - Mass association

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table `avail_requests` that has two foreign keys `avail_id` and `user_id`. An availability is created. Then a request is sent for that availability to every user in the system. Say I have 10 users, so after the request is sent, the table `avail_requests` should have 10 rows, with all their `avail_id` being the same, and the `user_id` being the 10 user ids.

How can I do this association directly with Laravel? Obviously I can loop through all the users and do this as follows:

```
// Assuming $users contains the Collection of all users
// Assuming $avail is the availability Collection
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    $request = new AvailRequest();
    $request->avail()->associate($avail);
    $request->user()->associate($user);
    $request->save();
}
```

Is there an easier way that doesn't involve looping?

Comment: Is it a model for the pivot table only, or do you really need it (ie. it holds other data too?)

Comment: It holds other data too. It's not just a pivot table.

Comment: But is it relevant in this case or this is all the code you want to execute? For there is nothing more, but foreign keys.

Comment: Creating a request is just the foreign key assignment. The rows have default column values than later on change as the users interact with the request.

Comment: So you can setup `belongsToMany` relation between `User` and `Availability`, then call `sync($ids, false)` - 2nd param in order to avoid detaching. Mind that it will run the same loop under the hood. Otherwise use `DB::table(..)->insert(..)` for single query.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I should rename the table to `avail_user` so that the pivot table automatically matches up. Okay that makes more sense. Thanks a lot! If you post this, I can mark it as a solutino.

Comment: There you go. You don't have to rename the table. Let it be the one that you feel comfortable with. In the end it's just a convention, that should help you, not make you change everything so it fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `avail_requests` is a pivot table linking `users` with `availabilites`, you can leverage `belongsToMany` relation.

So create this relation:

```
// I assume Availability is the model name
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'avail_requests', 'avail_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Then you can call `sync` to do the job for you:

```
$avail = Availability::find($someId);

$avail->users()->sync($usersIds, false); // 2nd param to false so it won't detach anything
```

---

Other solution would be the simplest thing possible:

```
$ids; // array of availability and users ids

DB::table('avail_requests')->insert($ids); // runs single insert query
```